# What does the〈 〉notation mean in this situation?

Tags: collision-resistance, notation

I was looking at solutions for a problem but I noticed it said $\langle2\rangle$ and was unsure of what that meant.

> [image: screenshot of relevant part]

From [Homework 5](https://umich.instructure.com/files/1468343/download?download_frd=1&verifier=1hqvwYhfpX5zhaJ6tVmo1Aa2ON0MVtYJakNVwAZj) (PDF)

Comment: That's a very strange notation to be used here. But the instructor as noted at the top corner of the paper, @chris-peikert who happens to be a member here, maybe we should ask him?

Comment: I've started a [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74424) with him, I'm not sure if you could join.

Comment: It appears from context that $\langle x \rangle$ is a canonical representation of the integer $x$  as an $n$- bit bitstring. Otherwise those inputs and outputs are not in the correct donation/range.

Comment: @Maeher So basically the solution demonstrated an attack on a artifical hash compression function that is collision resistant but not pseudo-random?

Comment: You also see this notation in quantum mechanics, as in part 1 of [Why should one model an entropy source in order to build a TRNG?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/68166/23115). Don't ask me, I just copied it but you see if often in photonic TRNG papers. It may have multiple meanings subject to domain.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about one instructor's nonstandard notation in one homework assignment that was probably due over a year ago, by an instructor who could have posted an answer on this site if it were significant.

Answer (score 2):

From the context of the exercise, it appears that $\langle x\rangle$ is meant to denote a canonical representation of the integer $x$ as a bitstring of length $n$.

If this were not the case, those inputs and outputs would not be in the correct  domain and range respectively.

Likely this notation was defined somewhere in the lecture notes, but I cannot find them at the moment.

Comment: Sounds like a very logical answer, in that case it is likely defined as I2OSP as defined in RSA (a statically sized, unsigned big endian / network order integer representation.